# Bijection between hom sets of equivalent categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I've been trying to prove the following claim, but am now unsure about its truth. Is it true, and if so, where can I find a proof?

**Claim:** For any categories C, D, E such that C and D are equivalent,

(i) The set $Hom($C, E$)$ of functors from C to E is in bijective correspondence with the set $Hom($D, E$)$ of functors from D to E, i.e. $Hom($C, E$)$ $\simeq$ $Hom($D, E$)$.

(ii) The set $Hom($E, C$)$ of functors from E to C is in bijective correspondence with the set $Hom($E, D$)$ of functors from E to D, i.e. $Hom($E, C$)$ $\simeq$ $Hom($E, D$)$.

Comment: These claims are not true. You can refute them using 1- or 2-object categories having the property that for any objects $A$ and $B$ there is a unique morphism from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: What is true is that the categories $\mathrm{Hom}(C,E)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(D,E)$ (and vice versa) are equivalent. Are there size issues here?

Comment: They equivalent because there is a bijective correspondence between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will turn my comment into an answer.

If $X$ is any nonempty set, then let ${\mathcal C}_X$ be the category
which has $X$ as its class of objects and, for each pair
$(x_1,x_2)\in X^2$, has exactly one morphism
$\varphi_{x_1,x_2}:x_1\to x_2$. Every morphism
in ${\mathcal C}_X$ is necessarily an isomorphism.

Any function $f: X\to Y$ is the object part of a unique
functor $F: {\mathcal C}_X\to {\mathcal C}_Y$,
and any two such functors are naturally isomorphic.
In particular, ${\mathcal C}_X$ and
${\mathcal C}_Y$ are categorically equivalent
for any nonempty $X$ and $Y$.

Hence for $X = \{0\}$, $Y = \{0,1\}$, and
${\sf C} = {\mathcal C}_X$, 
${\sf D} = {\sf E} = {\mathcal C}_Y$ we have
(i) $|\textrm{Hom}({\sf C}, {\sf E})| = 2$ and 
$|\textrm{Hom}({\sf D}, {\sf E})| = 4$, while 
(ii) $|\textrm{Hom}({\sf E}, {\sf C})| = 1$ and 
$|\textrm{Hom}({\sf E}, {\sf D})| = 4$.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks, this is very helpful. As a small follow up, what are some interesting examples of equivalent but non-isomorphic categories $C$ and $D$ which do satisfy both (i) and (ii) for any $E$?

Comment: @BenEva: I don't know if there exist such $C$ and $D$.